# Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "typhoeus" v. 1.3.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Incorporo en mi Gemfile:

```
gem 'khipu-api-client', '2.7.1'
gem 'typhoeus', '1.3.0'
```

Sin embargo genera el siguiente error al usar el comando : bundle install

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "typhoeus":

```
In Gemfile:
  typhoeus (= 1.3.0)

  khipu-api-client (= 2.7.1) was resolved to 2.7.1, which depends on
    typhoeus (>= 0.2.1, ~> 0.2)
```

Solicitando una version del typhoeus que no es posible instalar

¿Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema se debe a que estás especificando una versión de *typhoeus* diferente a la que necesita la gema *khipu-api-client*.

Si únicamente necesitas la gema *typhoeus* para utilizar *khipu-api-client*, entonces el problema se soluciona eliminando la línea `gem 'typhoeus', '1.3.0'` de tu *Gemfile*,  así automáticamente se instalará la versión adecuada de *typhoeus* en tu proyecto:

```
# Gemfile

gem 'khipu-api-client', '2.7.1'
```

Comment: Excelente! realizo lo que me comentas y descarga por defecto la version que necesita el khipu, sin embargo instalo una versión muy antigua del typhoeus y necesito minimo la 1.1.0 para que el resto de mi proyecto funcione. ¿Eso ya no depende de mi cierto? los desarrolladores de khipu deberian actualizar sus gemas?

Comment: @SamuelHeredia Es correcto, debes optar por utilizar una versión de la gema, así que podrías ponerte en contacto con los desarrolladores y ver si tienen interés en soportar nuevas versiones de la gema _typhoeus_ (e.g. a través de in _issue_) o bien, modificarla tu mismo (finalmente es código abierto), aunque esto es mucho más complicado.

Comment: Muchas Gracias! quedo claro